# Как во Flutter/Dart сделать вложенный горизонтальный список?

Tags: flutter, dart

Хочу реализовать вложенный горизонтальный список во Flutter.
list1 - вертикальная прокрутка, list2 - вертикальная на элемент list1.

Написал Stream.builder в Stream.builder - не работает.
Так как можно сделать такой список?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: MyHomePage(),
 );
}}
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
List<int> list1 = List();
List<int> list2 = List();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  list1.add(i);
     }
for (var j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
  list2.add(j);
   }
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list1.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: list2.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(list1[index].toString()),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }));
      }
      }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> list1 = List();
  List<int> list2 = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      list1.add(i);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
      list2.add(j);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list1.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 200.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical : 20),
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: list2.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(list1[index].toString()),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```